# How to create a Mysql table with monthnames from year 2000

Tags: python, mysql

How to create a Mysql table with column names as monthNumbers from year 2000 to till date.

Eg:

```
  CREATE TABLE abc_horizontal 
  (PRIMARY KEY (a_fips),
  a_fips INT(7),
  val_200001 DEC(8,4),
  val_200002 DEC(8,4),
  val_200003 DEC(8,4),
  val_200004 DEC(8,4), upto 201703 ?
```

Is there a shorter way to generate these val_yyyymm from 2000 till current month using python script?

Comment: Bad table design... MySQL has hard limit of 4096 columns per table, but the effective maximum may be less for a given table.read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/column-count-limit.html

Comment: some biz logic needed the horizontal table creation, Not sure if mysql is a wise choice as well. maybe a columnar db is better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Omg so many ways! Heres one ...

```
print( "\n".join([
    "CREATE TABLE abc_horizontal",
    "(PRIMARY KEY (a_fips)",
    ", a_fips INT(7)",
    "\n".join([ 
        ", val_20%02d%02d DEC(8,4)"%(x,y+1)
        for x in range(18)
        for y in range(12)
        if not (x == 17 and y >= 04) 
    ]),
    " );"
] ) )
```

What you PROBABLY really want is something like this though

```
CREATE TABLE abc_horizontal (
    PRIMARY KEY (a_fips, reporting_date), 
    a_fips INT(7), 
    reporting_date CHAR(6),
    value DEC(8,4)
);
```

Comment: in the 2nd create table are you suggesting a vertical table instead of a horizontal?

Comment: That would be the standard. And its not really 'vertical' so much as 'normalized'